# Backbone.js Router not detecting url change

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, socket.io, handlebars.js

Looking at this [example](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/) it appears that the router should detect links causing a change in URL that match its routes.  However, clicking on the link generated by my Handlebars template only changes the URL and does not trigger the alert in the router.  The route is, for some strange reason, triggered upon refresh, though the URL looses the hash.

I'm not sure why the router isn't picking up my URL change.  I'd prefer using links rather than Router.navigate if they do work.  The route does work for the default route.

The backbone.js code below is run on $(document).ready from a script in the html head.

#### Item Handlebars template

```
{{#with lobby}}
<li id="lobby-{{id}}">
    <div class="lobby_info">{{name}} - {{owner}} - {{player_count}}/18</div> <a href="#lobby/{{id}}">Join</a>
 </li>
 {{/with}}
```

#### Item Backbone View

```
var LobbyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click .lobby_info": "expand_toggle",
    },

    expand_toggle: function(evt) {
        alert('Expand toggle');
    },

    render: function() {
        var template = Handlebars.compile($("#lobby_template").html());

        this.$el.html(template(this.model.toJSON()));

        return this;
    }
});
```

#### Item Collection View

```
var LobbiesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "submit #create_lobby_form": "create_lobby",
    },

    create_lobby: function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault()

        var val = $('#lobby_name').val();

        socket.emit('create', val);

        $("#lobby_name").val("");
    },

    initialize: function() {
        var me = this;

        socket.on('create', function(lobby) {
            var lobby_item = new LobbyView({
                model: new LobbyModel({
                    lobby: lobby
                })
            });

            // render it to the DOM
            el = lobby_item.render().el;
            me.$("#lobbies").append(el);
       });

    },

    render: function() {
        var me = this;

        var template = Handlebars.compile($("#lobbies_template").html());

        $(this.el).html(template());

        return this;
    },
});
```

#### Router

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    // Match urls with methods
    routes: {
        "": "index",
        "lobby/:lobby_id": "lobby",
        "player/:player_id": "player"
    },

    index: function() {
        // connect to the websocket
        socket = io.connect();
        socket.emit('subscribe');
        var view = new LobbiesView({
            el: $("#container"),
        });

        view.render();
    },

    // View a lobby
    lobby: function(lobby_id) {
        alert('Viewing lobby' + lobby_id);
    },

    // View a player
    player: function(player_id) {
    },
});

// start backbone routing
var app = new Router();
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is `{ pushState: true }`. Remove it and your router will work (tested in console). If `pushState` is set to true, you need to set up routes without hashes.

This is the code I was testing:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "index",
        "lobby/:lobby_id": "lobby",
        "player/:player_id": "player",
        "*actions": "test"
    },

    test: function() { 
        console.log('test', arguments) 
    },

    index: function() {
        console.log('index', arguments);
    },

    player: function() {
        console.log('player', arguments);
    },

    lobby: function(lobby_id) {
        console.log('lobby', arguments);
    }
});

// start backbone routing
var app = new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Thanks!  The other example I was following was from python-socketio and it used `{pushState: true}`.  I didn't think to check what html5 push state actually meant.